# Could we have a request to merge topic with another documentation tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

It seems like currently there is no way to move a topic from one documentation tag to another. Example [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/topic-requests/450) should rather be at [RubyGems](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rubygems/topics) rather than Ruby language itself.

Would it be possible for us to have a vote to merge workflow?

There's also a discussion about [big documentation tags and sub tags being documented separately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329927/should-documentations-like-android-and-android-gradle-be-merged-together). Regardless the outcome the feature will be needed.

Comment: We're gonna have to build some move-topic and merge-tag stuff, so I'm tentatively [meta-tag:status-planned]-ing this.

Comment: Great, that would be a wonderful addition, thanks @KevinMontrose :)

Comment: @KevinMontrose, not sure if you'd rather this be a separate feature request, but I believe it'd also be helpful to be able to move examples between topics. Specifically, if you're closing a duplicate topic, but some of the examples are high-quality and deserve to be moved to the correct topic.

Comment: @BrendenKromhout moving examples within the same tag's topic is already available as I saw. it's just aside the edit button. am I wrong?

Comment: I've been actively avoiding some topics until they can be shared between tags to minimize the amount of mess that needs to be cleaned up if or when this is implemented.

Comment: @Lahiru, ah, I do see it now, perhaps I'd just missed it last night. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, there is an explosion of .NET Framework tag topics in C# tag..

Comment: I'm hoping this gets taken care of relatively soon...a lot of the pain points I'm encountering in Java documentation could be solved by this.

Comment: If this could be done soon, it would be a great improvement. The JavaFX examples in the java tag were deleted in favor of new topics in the JavaFX tag, thus removing all original contributions...

Comment: I hope this comes soon. The JavaScript tag is *out of control* with every web API getting documented all under JavaScript completely out of whack with Q&A

Comment: no answer for this yet? Same problem adding [tag:java]  tag to http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/json/drafts/63741

Comment: @KevinMontrose I'm not sure if this merits a full feature request because it would be kinda obscure, but would a "move example, then edit what's left" feature be useful and/or in the works?  So far, there's been one time when I wanted to move [an overly-large example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/508/classes-structures/17116/non-static-member-functions#t=20160809110505923) (~30k characters) into [a new topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/5661/non-static-member-functions) (and break it down into multiple examples),

Comment: then edit [the original example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/508/classes-structures/17116/non-static-member-functions) to be a short summary that links to the new topic.  (At this point, the example in question [was too large to add anything](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/80520?filter-tags=c%2b%2b).)

Comment: If I just used the "move example" feature, then to my understanding, the original example would be completely excised from the original topic, which was undesired; instead, I had to first create the new topic, then manually edit the original example, trimming it down to a summary & linking to the new topic.  It would be nice to have a "move, then edit original location" feature (or rather, a "copy, and edit original" feature), to streamline this process if any other examples need to be split off as distinct topics, while still retaining the link to the original topic.

Comment: (And yes, this situation came about because I tried to go too in-depth in a single example in the first place, but that's beside the point.  The point is that there are situations where an example would be better off being split into a full-on topic, but the original topic should retain some information on the subject, so I was curious whether there were any plans to implement functionality to make this easier to accomplish.)

Answer (score 0):

This hase been implemented, but it does not appear to be available for Suggested Topics, like the one you linked to.

I just attempted this myself on the "Regular Expression" topic in the C# tag. This topic should actually be in the .NET Framework tag - here are the steps I took to move it:

1. I started by creating a draft of the topic I wanted to move it to in the .NET Framework tag.
2. I then went to the the C# topic and selected "Move Examples" to the left of the Topic title.
3. I selected all the existing examples, and once I did that an additional check box appeared to confirm moving all the examples would delete the (C#) topic.
4. I selected "Select from your Drafts" and picked the draft I had started in step 1. <del>Apparently, Documentation currently only supports moving 6 examples (at one time?)</del> Documentation has put a 6 examples limit per topic in place since the C# topic was created, so I clicked "Edit Draft" of the "New Draft".

   [image: Must reduce example count to six or less before finishing move.]
5. I edited the "New Draft" as needed and clicked "Submit for Review"

Some things I learned:

- I initially started at step 2 and tried to select "Create a new Draft" in step 3, but I couldn't see where to specify that I wanted to move it to another tag, so I started over and used the method I outlined here.
- The change notes in my Proposed Change is "Delete topic,". I didn't think to add a change note in the "New Draft", so I think that is where it came from (a default value).
- In retrospect, perhaps I should have only copied six of the examples over, waited for that to get approved, then transferred the last example. I kinda thought about that, but I ended up picking (what I considered to be) a low quality example that was more about using the `$` string operator.