# Languages and the environments where they're used should have different tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, documentation

Right now the JavaScript section of Documentation is having a lot of topics and examples regarding one of its environments, the browser.

Node, which is another JS environment has its own section.

Personally I think we should stop this madness and create another section called something like "Browser scripting" and migrate all the topics related to browser APIs (DOM, Storage, WebWorkers, etc...) in JavaScript there.

I strongly believe the JavaScript section is going to get out of control if we don't do something about this.

**As big libraries are separated from their respective languages, so should be environments**

The [web-technologies tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-technologies) would be the best suited tag to be used in Documentation. It has 51 questions related only, we need 500. This makes it almost impossible to create the tag in documentation, it would be great if **someone at SO could give us a hand** here.

The other mayor issue is to have the possibility to [merge topics into another tag, but that's on its way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328723/could-we-have-a-request-to-merge-topic-with-another-documentation-tag)

---

There is a [topic request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topic-requests/1848) addressing this issue.

---

A new [tag for the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dom) has been created. We're stil missing a tag for Web APIs.

Comment: I agree with this -- between node.js and DOM operations, the JavaScript tag could contain 50% of answers that may be entirely irrelevant to a given viewer of the tag. Something should be done earlier rather than later to better categorize these very disparate categories of use of the same high-level language to avoid clutter on SERPs, at the very least?

Comment: [It's been discussed before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics) but I think a great solution to this would be at least one more layer in the hierarchy. Then it could be JavaScript -> Node/Browser/etc. -> Topics -> Examples.

Comment: I think JavaScript deserves to be considered as a scripting language that *can* do web, but is not limited to that. What about "JavaScript > Web development > Front end > Examples" ? Nowadays, it can be used for back end (i.e. with NodeJS), and even be used for infra scripts as well (i.e. with Gulp.js).

Comment: I don't think we should solve this with more hierarchy. I think that the OP has it correct; each environment should have its own tag. JavaScript is a full-fledged language in its own right and deserves to be documented as well as C#, Java, or any other language that coincidentally runs in a VM.

Comment: Please distinguish between [the DOM](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) and [the web platform](https://platform.html5.org/); do not use "the DOM" when you mean "the web platform".

Comment: @Domenic The dom is a sub-category of the web platform, isn't it? I think we don't need a "web-platform" tag.

Comment: In that case where will you put questions about, e.g. IndexedDB or service workers or custom elements? Those are not part of the DOM.

Comment: [WEB APIs tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330074/the-web-apis-documentation-tag)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that JavaScript is not the place for Web-APIs, but I'm not convinced by an even broader "*web-technonlogies-tag*".

**Let's have a tag per Web-API.**

As already said, Web-APIs are more than just DOM or JavaScript, each has its own methods, bias, way of doing, that may be related between each others, but may also not be related at all.

I'll take the [canvas] example, and in particular, the CanvasRenderingContext2d API, which is already completely different from the Web-GL API, even if based on the same HTMLCanvasElement.

We already have [a lot of mess in main](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=canvas) with its tags ([canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas), [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas)), but it's becoming even worth in documentation, where there are already a bunch of unsorted examples as a [JavaScript subset](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/525/2d-canvas) and also [its own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas) that I personnaly find better. *Note that a [third one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/canvas) is currently in proposal.*

Most of the topics on the new one will be duplicates of the ones already written, but these have the advantage of being correctly sorted by field (path drawings, media drawings, and I can also see coming a Compositings, animation etc.).

If not useful for readers which will use google as I read somewhere (still not convinced about it), I can already say that for those who want to participate as authors in this field, it's way easier to have everything well sorted. This won't be possible to do so if this tag is just a topic of some broader tag.

Also, for those who say that Web-APIs are specific to the DOM, I'd tell them that canvas API has (almost) nothing to do with the DOM, the only link to the DOM is the `createElement` method to get the first HTMLCanvasElement. Everything else is just made from the API. JavaScript is not either the proper place since even if most of us use JavaScript, one could also write a C implementation to interact with this API.