# Separate topics for languages and tools, or rename the topics

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-proposals

I noticed that the "Python **Language**" documentation tag is starting to accumulate examples for tool usage (e.g. PIP). I was thinking about adding a topic for the pyenv Python version and virtual environment management tool, but I realized that pyenv is not a language feature. If there were such thing as documentation sub-topics (which would be nice) we could rename the Python Language tag to Python and create a sub-topic for Python tools. However, as there are no such thing, might it be beneficial to create a new documentation tag called "Python Tools" and move topics related to tools rather than the language itself there?

Of course, I'm just using Python as an example, because that is where I've done most of my work in Stack Overflow documentation, but this can be something to consider for all languages that have a lot of tools, both official and third-party.

Comment: Do pip really have bad documentation? Isn't it a simple package manager-y?

Comment: @Braiam:  It *might* have poor documentation in areas, which implies that it's okay for a topic to be created.  However, I'm along the side of the OP here in that I could program Python all day without really *requiring* PIP.  I'm not sure where we'd want to place it though.  Perhaps it does belong under its own subsection.

Comment: @Makoto I'm sure there are people that can apply for [the pip](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pip) tag. Only include a topic in the way of "managing python modules" in the [python] tag and including all the methods of managing modules along with links to their respective tags for more information.

Comment: I still think it might be beneficial to have some separation for python tools in general. There aren't an overwhelming number of them, but I think it would go a long way to navigability if they were categorized neatly and easy to find. I'm not sure that a new user would go to the "Python Language" tag looking to learn how PIP or conda works.

Comment: Of course you won't! You will go to the pip or conda tags instead.

Comment: Very closely related: [Languages and the environments where they're used should have different tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328778)