# Should documentations like 'android' and 'android-gradle' be merged together?

Tags: discussion, documentation

## The issue

We currently have [`android` documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android) and [`android-gradle` documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-gradle) as separate documentations. Both document `android-gradle` to some extent.

What is the Stackoverflow guidelines for cases like these? Should they be merged? Should we actively encourage splitting arguments into sub-topics?

I'm using `android` as an example, this apply to any major tag with lot of arguments (and sub-tags) related to it.

### To those unfamiliar with Android

`gradle` is a build / dependency management tool more or less like Maven, somewhat like `make` in `C`. This can be used to build many different types of software with many different languages, and is rightfully a separate tag that deserves its own documentation. Nothing to argue here.

`android-gradle` is a gradle plugin, created and maintained by Google, that provides the means to build, sign, and configure Android applications and libraries on top of `gradle`.

### Duplicated effort

I think they DO makes sense as separate tags for stackoverflow. I'm not so sure about documentation.

There are many topics related to `android-gradle` to be covered and they deserve to be documented.

While `android` applications and libraries *can* be written without `android-gradle` (almost no one does that) the opposite can't be said: there's no `android-gradle` without `android`, it simply makes no sense.

If you look at the two documentations you'll see there are many duplicated topics, [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=android&query=gradle) `gradle` inside the `android` documentation show there are many topics about it.

There was a discussion about this yesterday on the documentation chat, it started with my message [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31969353#31969353) and went on for a while between me, @Shog9 @DanielNugent, @Makoto, and later @Onur and @TravisJ. The conclusion of this discussion was that this is something that needs to be discussed in a meta.

### Decision to be made

I also think the discussion is not limited to Android vs Android Gradle but in general to situation like this one.

The community should give a clear guidelines on how to handle cases like this choosing between:

- `android` and `android-gradle` makes sense as separate documentations: thus any topic about `android-gradle` should be rejected in android / moved to `android-gradle`
- `android` and `android-gradle` DO NOT makes sense as separate documentations: all topics should be merged into `android` and the creation of `android-gradle` discouraged

As a reference, a [similar argument](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags) has been brought up about `java` and `java-8`. However the situation here is not the same, `android-gradle` is not a version of android, it is a tool you can use to build android application that wouldn't exist without `android`.

## Related Feature requests

Whichever decision the community make I think **we need** a manner **to move documentation topics** from one documentation to the other. Possibly allowing **merging documentations**. Follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328723/could-we-have-a-request-to-merge-topic-with-another-documentation-tag) feature request.

If the decision is to merge them together I think we also need some way of sectioning the documentation into big topics that can have their specific maintainers / subscribers. Follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330060/feature-request-sections-to-better-organize-documentation) feature request.

Comment: When I click on the Android tag, I want to see topics on everything that is essential to build an Android app. Consider someone new to Android who has no idea what Gradle is, and that it's essential if using Android Studio. They wouldn't even know to back out of the main Android tag and search for a more obscure tag. I think that as long as it is maintainable, everything that is essential to Android development should live under one roof. Doing otherwise would make the main Android tag seem incomplete without further investigation. So, my personal preference is the second choice.

Comment: I agree with @DanielNugent for the most part. On the other side having them separed makes it easier for the maintainer to focus and organize a topic well. I subscribed to both android and android-gradle. There was too many notification on Android and i couldn't really focus on a single argument. I think that should be addressed as well.

Comment: Possibly related: The tag [tag:visual-studio] already exists and there are proposals for [tag:visual-studio-2010], [tag:visual-studio-2012], [tag:visual-studio-2013] and [tag:visual-studio-2015]. Are these version-specific tags of any real use? Should they be made synonyms of [tag:visual-studio]?

Comment: @AdrianHHH that's like java vs java-8. It's versions. This is not the same thing. That's already been routed out here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags

Comment: So, what is this? A discussion _or_ a feature request? Feature requests can _still_ be discussed. As the discussion tag says: _"If it is **not a** bug or **feature-request**, it is probably a discussion."_

Comment: it's a discussion: completely fall in *"questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective"*. And has a feature request which is related but secondary to the discussion. Should the feature request be splitted into a separate question? It depends on the outcome of this discussion.

Comment: The feature request should probably be a question on it's own, as it applies to documentation as a whole. Not just to the mentioned tags.

Comment: @Cerbrus this apply to the documentation as a whole. It's not a question about android and android-gradle. That's only the perfect case to discuss about and to be applied elsewhere.