# Feature Request: sections to better organize documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Big, major topics have lot of contributors and editors and many sub-arguments.

Currently an editor / contributor can decide to follow proposal or topic request for a single tag, as a whole. When there are big arguments with lot of contributors this quickly become unbearable (too many notifications).

I think it should be easier for editors to just follow a single or a couple of sub-argument of a documentation tag.

It would also help naturally create maintainer of those sections and an hierarchy of maintainer.

This is possibly the reason people are creating distinct documentation tags like [`android`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android) and [`android-gradle`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-gradle), check this [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329927/should-documentations-like-android-and-android-gradle-be-merged-together) going on about it.

Unless we [decide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329927/should-documentations-like-android-and-android-gradle-be-merged-together) this separation is fine I think we should add some way to sections documentations into multiple arguments / category / sub-tags, at least from the editor perspective.