# Documentation: Has there been any discussion around related/linked documentation topics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Has there been any discussion of how to re-use or group together documentation that is relevant to multiple technologies?  Linux seems like a big problem in general.  Ubuntu, Mandrake, Puppy, Red Hat, Debian, Knoppix all have more similarities than differences.  The UIs are related, but different, the administration, related but different, but in general, most of the user level commands are the same, modulo a version difference between releases.  When you expand to all Unix-like, (HPUX, AIX, Solaris, Ultrix (yes, yes, UNIX proper is almost dead)) many more operations are the are similar but different (different options, different caveats) and some operations are radically different between unix flavors (mostly at the system administration of Disks and Storage level). To have an "vi" or "ls" topic for each one of those seems like a untenable situation, yet polluting ls and vi with x y and z specific options/operations makes for documentation that's hard to follow for a given technology...   In general, with the current flatness, there is a no-win choice all in one or split apart topics, i.e., put all topics under "Linux" with a distribution attached to various examples, or deal with the duplication that stems from having a tag for each distribution...

Another example is Regular Expressions. Ruby, javascript, python and Perl are all very similar in their treatment of regexp operations, but the current Topic is very much a mish mash and hard to focus on the language you want to use.  It's true it's a problem on the question side too [meta regexp tags, do we split it by engine?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317596/split-the-regex-tag) When you go to C#, java, etc, the usage takes on a different flavor, and each engine has its feature differences.

Tags seem too flat for documentation; The ability to lay a hierarchy on top of a set of tags and examples would help, but yes, it adds complexity and isn't clear a UI could deal nicely with two views of the same/similar examples.

Comment: The idea of adding a hierarchy to Documentation [has been discussed before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics). [Many](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330060/feature-request-sections-to-better-organize-documentation), [many](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330038/215552) times...

Comment: @JF Yeah, ok.  Discussed and kicked down the road for later.  OK.  I guess when there is "infinite" manpower to adapt to changes, it's a tenable position.

Comment: Fine, "sufficient" manpower is better.  only a Boss wants infinite manpower.