# The WEB APIs documentation tag

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-tags

Once [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328723/could-we-have-a-request-to-merge-topic-with-another-documentation-tag) reach [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), we should [alias](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329860/248058) the following SO tags—out the top of my head—to an all-encompassing general-purpose WEB APIs documentation tag:

- [xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlhttprequest)
- [w3c-geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-geolocation)
- [html5-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-notifications)
- [indexeddb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexeddb)
- [fetch-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch-api)
- [fileapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileapi)
- [form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-data)
- [webcryptoapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcryptoapi)
- [web-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-worker)
- [service-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-worker)
- [shared-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-worker)
- [web-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio)
- …

related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/topic-requests/1848
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI
- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_other
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Answer (score 2):

Yet another why we need the Web APIs tag: [Web Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/428/web-storage#t=201607291732016128266) is versioned separately from JavaScript and wasn't even formally standardized until HTML5.

- `localStorage` was introduced in Firefox in version 3.5, which corresponds roughly with JS 1.8.1, which itself corresponds very roughly with ES 5.1.
- It was also available in IE8, which still used JScript, at a version roughly equivalent to ES 3.

So what version of JavaScript should the Web Storage topic be set to?

Currently it's set as "All Versions", but it was obviously not available back in version 1.

Unfortunately, the [web-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-storage) tag only has 171 questions, and the [sessionstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sessionstorage) tag <sub>(yay for consistent naming)</sub> has even fewer at 96. [local-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-storage) is the winner with a whopping 4317 questions, but only defines one aspect of the Web Storage API... Argh.

Comment: If you check the Docs tags created from Q&A tags you'll see they all have the same name. I'm supposing at some point we're going to be able to change the name of the Doc tag, and we could at that point change from local-storage to Web Storage API, and voilá! Anyways I think we're going to merge them togheter so... who cares about the name?

Comment: Good point, @MarcoScabbiolo. I assumed the merge would somehow use the tag name in order to merge like-named topics/examples, but there's a slim possibility I'm over-engineering the merge logic in my head...

Comment: http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/how-to-handle-this-particular-case?noredirect=1

Comment: Thanks @Knu, I was asleep for most of the private beta, so I missed all this. I hope we can get these tags created soon, because boy am I tired of seeing more and more documentation of it showing up in JavaScript.